# Get the value in HTML list from an xml using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt-2.0

Below there are two lists (`sub1`, `sub2`) in XML. Can we write an XSLT for converting them in HTML with `ol` tags?

```
<sub1>
  <number>(1)</number>
  <para-text align="left" indent="0">XYZ</para-text>
  <sub2>
    <number>(a)</number>
    <para-text align="left" indent="0">ABC</para-text>
  </sub2>
  <sub2>
    <number>(b)</number>
    <para-text align="left" indent="0">DEF</para-text>
  </sub2>
  <sub2>
    <number>(c)</number>
    <para-text align="left" indent="0">GHI</para-text>
  </sub2>
</sub1>
```

I have used the below template (value for current node) but was not able to succeed.

```
<xsl:template match="/sub1">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <xsl:for-each select="para-text">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()" /> </xsl:for-each>
    </li>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

The HTML structure which i am looking for is like

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is appreciated when you take the time to show what research you've done into the problem you're having, and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. Stack Overflow exists to help people solve problems in programming, not write code based on request.

Comment: i have used the below template (value for current node) but was not able to succeed.                                                                                                   
  <xsl:template match="/sub1">
  <ol>
   <li>
    <xsl:for-each select="para-text">
     <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Which HTML structure do you want to generate for the XML input sample? You say you have two lists `sub1` and `sub2` but your input sample has one `sub1` element and three `sub2` elements. How do you want to map them exactly to HTML?